# Bad converting String to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a problem with converting String to NSDate. In my text field when user tap on it, is a possibility to chose a date using `UIDatePicker`. `String` as a date in `TextField` looks like that: "yyyy-mm-dd" Now when I try to convert date for example on 2016-05-13 using this method:

```
func changeStringToNSDate(){

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
let from = moreSorts.fromDatePickerTextField.text!
let fromDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(from)

print(fromDate)

}
```

When I print `fromDate`I recieve an information that `fromDate` is not 2016-05-13 but 2016-01-11 23:58:00 +0000. I don't know why I have 2016-01-11 when in my `TextField` String shows 2016-05-13

Comment: You need to use the correct date format specifiers. Look at the docs.

Comment: can you write me correct format?

Comment: Look at the documentation and see if you can figure out what you done incorrectly. It's an important skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what might be going wrong for sure with the information you've provided. In a Swift playground I'm getting 2016-01-13 and not 2016-01-11, but if I change the date format, I can get 2016-05-13:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

The uppercase MM is key. I would check out this website to play around with the date format options:

http://nsdateformatter.com

Comment: when I print `fromDate` after correcting to yyyy-MM-dd I have one day less than normal. It means that in String I have 2016-05-13 but when I print `from Date` I receive 2016-05-12. Any suggestions why?

Comment: I'd maybe look into documentation on time zone handling for NSDate. Without knowing more, I'm not able to offer much more helpful advice. Trial and error along with documentation and swift playgrounds is probably your best bet from here.